# MATLAB - create a list for multiple files

Tags: matlab

I dont know if the title is appropriate, but i need to import several files e.g. 25 (files like info.asd , ina.asd, sdd.asd etc). So in my opinion its possible to import them via a for loop instead of hardcoding the operation. Any ideas how to implement the list in matlab, so the software 'd know what to import?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without loop with this function. sPath is the path containing your files and sExt is the extension of the files you want to list.

```
function cList = fileList(sPath, sExt)

    if nargin == 1
        sExt = '.asd';
    end

    % List files in the given path
    stDir = dir(sPath);
    tDir  = struct2table(stDir);
    tFile = tDir(~tDir.isdir, :);

    % Keep only file with the right extension
    cList  = tFile.name;
    [~, cList, cExt]  = cellfun(@fileparts     , ...
                                cList          , ...
                                'UniformOutput', false);
    vIsIni            = cellfun(@(x) strcmpi(x, sExt), cExt);
    cList = cList(vIsIni);
end
```

Comment: I want to cycle through them in order to get some plots as well, so a for loop would do it for both tasks

Comment: Ok, but you have to know how many times you have to loop before to initialize the counter variable in your for loop. You can use this function to know how much file you have and then start the loop to get the plots.

Comment: I suppose it will work with setting the counter to length(list).